# Passing parameter to SQL Function in plpgsql

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have written the below function and it works in Postgres 12.5:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION export_to_s3()
        RETURNS TRIGGER
AS $export_to_s3$
BEGIN
        PERFORM aws_s3.query_export_to_s3(
                'select * from test.allowed_object_status',
                aws_commons.create_s3_uri(
                        'test-db-dumps',
                        'allowed_object_status.csv',
                        'eu-west-2'),
                options :='format csv, delimiter $$,$$'
        );
        RETURN NEW;
END;
$export_to_s3$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Now i would like to make `test.allowed_object_status` and `allowed_object_status.csv` parameters that i pass into export_to_s3().

I have tried a few things but failed so any help would be great.
A second part to my question and less important is it possible for a function to return nothing/void. I made this function a trigger but thats only because I cant figure out how to declare a function that dose not return anything after executing

**Solution**
This the solution i come up with thanks to the comments from @404 below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION export_to_s3(query_cmd text, bucket_prefix text)
RETURNS VOID
AS $export_to_s3$
BEGIN
PERFORM
    aws_s3.query_export_to_s3(
        query_cmd,
        aws_commons.create_s3_uri(
            'test-db-dumps',
            bucket_prefix,
            'eu-west-2'),
        options :='format csv, delimiter $$,$$'
    );
END;
$export_to_s3$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I am sure there is a better way of doing it but very new to plpgsql

Comment: Just to be clear, are you actually looking to make a trigger function or just a regular function? If it needs to be a trigger then maybe you can get those values in there by setting environment variables somewhere which the trigger function reads... if it doesn't need to be a trigger function then it's much easier, just a standard function with params. "is it possible to a function to return nothing" - "a function", yes of course, define it as `RETURNS VOID`; but it's not clear if it needs to be a trigger function or not.

Comment: hey @404, apologies for the bad writing and confusion. Yes it should be a function that return nothing so i will use what you suggested ```RETURNS VOID```. How would i pass parameter to it ?

Comment: Ok if it's just a regular function then see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html for how to use params etc. A trigger function is a bit different, and a regular function can't be used as a trigger.

Comment: @404 this was enough for me to come up a solution ... if you like to provide it as an answer would be happy to accept it as such. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can pass arguments to a trigger function, but that works different than you'd imagine.

- You declare the trigger function **without parameters**.
- In the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement, you specify **string literals** as function arguments.
- These parameters can be accessed in the PL/pgSQL function body through `TG_ARGV[]`, and the argument count is in `TG_NARGS`.

See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-DML-TRIGGER) for details.